# submit form using django - referenced before assignment

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

1. why its sending this error local variable 'user' referenced before
   assignment 
        given below is my code
        add_new_vendor this is my function 
        here its showing error

   UnboundLocalError at /add_new_vendor/
       local variable 'user' referenced before assignment

   ```
   Request Method: POST
   Request URL: http://freedomclub.in/add_new_vendor/
   Django Version: 1.9
   Python Executable: /usr/local/bin/python
   Python Version: 2.7.14


   @api_view(['POST'])
   def add_new_vendor(request):
   if request.method == 'POST':
   merch =  
   Profile.objects.filter(vendor_pincode=request.POST.get('vendor_pincode'
                              , ''),

   vendor_category=request.POST.get('vendor_category'
                              , '')).count()
   resp_data = {}
   vendor_name = request.POST.get('vendor_name', '')
   user_id = request.POST.get('user_id', '')


   if merch == 0:
       user = Profile.objects.create(
           user_id=user_id,
           vendor_name=vendor_name)


       user.save()
       if merch > 0:
       return Response({'error': False, 'status': 202,
                       'message': 'Merchant already avaliable'})
       if user == 1:
       return Response({'error': False, 'status': 200,
                       'message': 'Registration Complete'})
   return Response({'error': False, 'status': 201,
               'message': 'Sorry Please Try Again'})
   ```

Comment: yes i have done my  code

Comment: Please fix your indentation. The full traceback will tell you which line the error is occuring on.

Comment: @Alasdair now i solved it yes this was indentation problem thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the error because you try to access `user` without having defined it.

Your variable `merch` is a queryset and `user` is a profile instance.

```
merch = Profile.objects.filter(vendor_pincode=request.POST.get('vendor_pincode'
                       , ''),

user = Profile.objects.create(
    user_id=user_id,
    vendor_name=vendor_name)
```

Therefore it doesn't make sense to compare them to integers.

```
if merch == 0:
...
if merch > 0:
...
if user == 1:
```

None of these conditions will ever be true. What are you trying to check here?

Perhaps you want to use [`exists()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#exists) to check whether `merch` exists:

```
if not merch.exists():
    ...
```

Comment: now i solved it yes this was indentation problem thank you

Comment: Fixing the indentation might stop the error, but you also need to change the if statements otherwise the code will not behave as you expect.